# Salesforce Paypal Integration(PayFlow)

Tags: rest, paypal, salesforce

I am using Rest API to get security token using unique securityID and other parameters.Please suggest. I am using following code :

```
HttpRequest httpRequest = new HttpRequest();
httpRequest.setEndpoint('https://pilot-payflowpro.paypal.com');
String body = 'PARTNER=Paypal&PWD=pwd&VENDOR=abc&USER=abc&CREATESECURERTOKEN=Y&SECURETOKENID=9a9ea8208de1413abc3d60c86cb1f4ce&TRXTYPE=C&AMT=23.0&MODE=TEST';
httpRequest.setBody(body);
httpRequest.setMethod('GET');
Http htt = new hTTP();
HttpResponse httpRe = htt.send(httpRequest);
system.debug(httpRe.geTbody());
```

But I am getting following error : RESULT=2&PNREF=A7X06D187FF7&RESPMSG=Invalid tender

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing one parameter here while posting data to "https://pilot-payflowpro.paypal.com". You need to include **TENDER=C** in your request parameters.

Second, you need to replace the **TRXTYPE=C to TRXTYPE=S** because TRXTYPE=C indicates it'sa refund transaction but you are performing a sale transaction .

It should similar to the below :

```
NVP Request:
VENDOR=XXXXXXXXX&PARTNER=XXXXXXXXX&USER=XXXXXXXXX&PWD==XXXXXXXXX&AMT=12.72&TRXTYPE=S&TENDER=C&SECURETOKENID=wsw.big7jsa8la531f4x31ec3ssael7esef1.4521352289&CREATESECURETOKEN=Y

NVP Response:
RESULT=0
RESPMSG=Approved
SECURETOKEN=99UhUOS2ZWk6wDJn8kdNNeAZf
SECURETOKENID=wsw.big7jsa8la531f4x31ec3ssael7esef1**
```

Hope this helps you debug your issue .